# Drools arraylist access

Tags: drools

How can i create a list from some POJO's property
which are in an arraylist,
on the LHS in a rule file?

For example :

```
class Employee{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    /* setter-getter */
 }
```

I have a list of employees in the working memory as
fact. And i would like to create a list
from employees first name on the LHS.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to have the Employees as facts instead of a list of them. It makes it easier to identify your facts. Then you could write something like:

```
when
    $names: Set(empty != false) 
        from accumulate ( Employee($fn: firstName), collectSet($fn) )
then
```

Best regards